# How to create \topsep when there is no preceding text

Tags: lists

The following MWE demonstrates two lists, each of which follows a header.  In the first case, the list items are arranged in a single column as usual.  In the second case, the list is broken into two columns by way of `minipages`.  Because no text precedes the lists in these minipages, the list parameter `\topsep` is suppressed, and the lists crowd the header. Is it possible to induce `\topsep` here in the absence of preceding text?  If not, how can vertical space be created to EXACTLY match the `\topsep` of the first list?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Header 1
\begin{itemize}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \item Third item
    \item Fourth item
\end{itemize}

\medskip

\noindent
Header 2

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{2in}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item First item
        \item Second item
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{2in}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Third item
        \item Fourth item
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried inserting the instruction `\vspace{\topsep}`?

Comment: @Mico Yes, but `\vspace` seems to introduce a new line and I'm not certain how to precisely counteract this.

Comment: Please see the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting a `\vspace{\topsep}` instruction between "Header 2" and the start of the `minipage` should do the job. Note that in the example below, I've switched to a `twocolumn` layout to ease the visual comparison of the vertical offsets.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example
\begin{document}

Header 1
\begin{itemize}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \item Third item
    \item Fourth item
\end{itemize}

\newpage % force a column break

Header 2

\vspace{\topsep}  % <--- new

\begin{minipage}[t]{1.5in}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item First item
        \item Second item
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{1.5in}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Third item
        \item Fourth item
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly.  In implementing your original suggestion, I mistakenly put the `\vspace` between the `minipage` and list.  But this created a new line/preceding text which induced and then compounded `\topsep`!  Thanks for the MWE.